# Where can I find some inspiration for mobile game user interfaces?

Tags: gui-design, mobile

I'm trying to develop a game on a mobile platform and I'm having a lot of trouble developing a diablo-like equipment screen.  I'm having trouble fitting all useful information on one dialog.  Inventory, inventory item stats, currently equipped item stats, a delete button, etc.  I was hoping I could look at some UIs of other similar games but I'm not really finding any sites dedicated to showing off good mobile game ui design ideas/patterns.

Comment: What about checking the mobile stores? Many games have free versions, and I believe the usually low cost (at least project budget-wise) would not suffer much even if you needed to buy such a game to look at the construction of the interface. I would start from the most popular ones (reading comments, some may regard interface) or ask Google about most popular RPGs for given platform, you would get e.g.: http://ipad.about.com/od/rpg/tp/Best-RPGs-For-The-iPad-Role-Playing.htm I know each game is specific, but this is something you will have to deal yourself or ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. [paulrandpierce.com](http://paulrandpierce.com/)**

[image]

**2. [tappgala.com](http://www.tappgala.com/)**

[image]

**3. [pinterest.com](http://pinterest.com/bsevers/games-apps-ui/)**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem while I was developing my own game, so I decided to just build such a website.

The website is called [game-patterns.com](http://www.game-patterns.com) and is a showcase of screens from various mobile games, categorized into important patterns (i.e Level Selection, Tutorial, in-app store etc.)

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic

Comment: And here I was thinking of creating a website like this :)